# Getting DTE2 reference throws exception

Tags: vsix, envdte

[As instructed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68shb4dw.aspx), I use the following line to get the DTE2 instance in a menu item callback in a VSIX extension.

```
dte2 = (DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0");
```

This has started crashing, perhaps since I ported the VSIX to Visual Studio 2017. I get a mystery dialog that says "operation not available", or sometimes "Invalid class string (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401F3(CO_E_CLASSSTRING))"

What happened ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct way is

EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2 = base.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE)) as EnvDTE80.DTE2;

Not to mention that 12.0 is for VS 2013 not for VS 2017.

Comment: where are you when you do this? What is `base` ?

Comment: inside a package